# Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

I would like to read several CSV files from a directory into pandas and concatenate them into one big DataFrame. I have not been able to figure it out though. Here is what I have so far:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Get data file names
path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

# Concatenate all data into one DataFrame
big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

I guess I need some help within the *for* loop?

Answer (score 882, accepted):

See [pandas: IO tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html) for all of the available `.read_` methods.

Try the following code if all of the CSV files have the same columns.

I have added `header=0`, so that after reading the CSV file's first row, it can be assigned as the column names.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "/*.csv"))

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Or, with attribution to a comment from [Sid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888455/sid).

```py
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
```

---

- It's often necessary to identify each sample of data, which can be accomplished by adding a new column to the dataframe.
- [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard library will be used for this example. It treats paths as objects with methods, instead of strings to be sliced.

#### Imports and Setup

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'  # or unix / linux / mac path

# Get the files from the path provided in the OP
files = Path(path).glob('*.csv')  # .rglob to get subdirectories
```

#### Option 1:

- Add a new column with the file name

```py
dfs = list()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
    # .stem is method for pathlib objects to get the filename w/o the extension
    data['file'] = f.stem
    dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

#### Option 2:

- Add a new column with a generic name using `enumerate`

```py
dfs = list()
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
    data['file'] = f'File {i}'
    dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

#### Option 3:

- Create the dataframes with a list comprehension, and then use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to add a new column.

  - `[f'S{i}' for i in range(len(dfs))]` creates a list of strings to name each dataframe.
  - `[len(df) for df in dfs]` creates a list of lengths
- Attribution for this option goes to this plotting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65951915/7758804).

```py
# Read the files into dataframes
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]

# Combine the list of dataframes
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Add a new column
df['Source'] = np.repeat([f'S{i}' for i in range(len(dfs))], [len(df) for df in dfs])
```

#### Option 4:

- One liners using [`.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create the new column, with attribution to a comment from [C8H10N4O2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573061/c8h10n4o2)

```py
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f).assign(filename=f.stem) for f in files), ignore_index=True)
```

or

```py
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f).assign(Source=f'S{i}') for i, f in enumerate(files)), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 369):

An alternative to [darindaCoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/3888455):

```
path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'                     # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
# doesn't create a list, nor does it append to one
```

Comment: @Mike @Sid the final two lines can be replaced by: `pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)`. The inner brackets are required by Pandas version 0.18.1

Comment: I recommend using `glob.iglob` instead of `glob.glob`; The first one returns and [iterator (instead of a list)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob).

Answer (score 121):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "my_files*.csv"))))
```

Comment: Excellent one liner, specially useful if no read_csv arguments are needed!

Comment: If, on the other hand, arguments are needed, this can be done with lambdas: `df = pd.concat(map(lambda file: pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True), data_files))`

Comment: ^ or with `functools.partial`, to avoid lambdas

Answer (score 94):

Almost all of the answers here are either unnecessarily complex (glob pattern matching) or rely on additional third-party libraries. You can do this in two lines using everything Pandas and Python (all versions) already have built in.

### For a few files - one-liner

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, ['d1.csv', 'd2.csv','d3.csv']))
```

### For many files

```
import os

filepaths = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths))
```

### For No Headers

If you have specific things you want to change with pd.read_csv (i.e., no headers) you can make a separate function and call that with your map:

```
def f(i):
    return pd.read_csv(i, header=None)

df = pd.concat(map(f, filepaths))
```

---

This pandas line, which sets the df, utilizes three things:

1. [Python's map (function, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) sends to the function (the
   `pd.read_csv()`) the iterable (our list) which is every CSV element
   in filepaths).
2. Panda's [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function reads in each CSV file as normal.
3. Panda's [concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) brings all these under one df variable.

Comment: or just `df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('data/*.csv))`

Comment: I tried the method prescribed by @muon. 

But, i have multiple files with headers(headers are common). I don't want them to be concatenated in the dataframe. Do you know how can i do that ?

I tried `df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv(header=0), glob.glob('data/*.csv))` but it gave an error "parser_f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath_or_buffer'"

Comment: It's a little while since you asked... but I updated my answer to include answers without headers (or if you want to pass any change to read_csv).

Answer (score 84):

## Easy and Fast

Import two or more CSV files without having to make a list of names.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('data/*.csv')))
```

Comment: How do we pass arguments to this syntax?

Comment: My answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994928/10358768, inspired from this particular answer!

Comment: @delimiter, to insert the file path to your docs, replace the word 'data' with your file path, and keep the / at the end.

Answer (score 63):

The Dask library can read a dataframe from multiple files:

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_csv('data*.csv')
```

(Source: https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Read-CSV-files)

The Dask dataframes implement a subset of the Pandas dataframe API. If all the data fits into memory, you can [call `df.compute()`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute) to convert the dataframe into a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Similar to this, there should be a function in pandas API for reading multiple files in a dir. Apparently it does not have it, as now.

Comment: Does this work with AWS S3 paths too?

Answer (score 23):

I googled my way into [Gaurav Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/186078).

However, as of late, I am finding it faster to do any manipulation using [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and then assigning it once to a dataframe rather than manipulating the dataframe itself on an iterative basis and it seems to work in this solution too.

I do sincerely want anyone hitting this page to consider this approach, but I don't want to attach this huge piece of code as a comment and making it less readable.

You can leverage NumPy to really speed up the dataframe concatenation.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "my_dir_full_path"
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv"))


np_array_list = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())

comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)
big_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)

big_frame.columns = ["col1", "col2"....]
```

Timing statistics:

```
total files :192
avg lines per file :8492
--approach 1 without NumPy -- 8.248656988143921 seconds ---
total records old :1630571
--approach 2 with NumPy -- 2.289292573928833 seconds ---
```

Comment: Any numbers to back the "speed up"? Specifically, is it faster than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe/36073025#comment57648172_21232849 ?

Comment: I don't see the OP asking for a way to speed up his concatenation, this just looks like a rework of a pre-existing accepted answer.

Comment: That won't work if the data has mixed columns types.

Comment: @SKG perfect.. this is the only working solution for me. 500 files 400k rows total in 2 secs. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: 1500 files and 750k rows in 5 secs. Excellent @SKG

Comment: '    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())' showing an error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Comment: df.as_matrix() is Deprecated since version 0.23.0: Use DataFrame.values() instead.

Answer (score 17):

A one-liner using `map`, but if you'd like to specify additional arguments, you could do:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import functools

df = pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_csv, sep='|', compression=None),
                    glob.glob("data/*.csv")))
```

Note: `map` by itself does not let you supply additional arguments.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to **search recursively** (*Python 3.5 or above*), you can do the following:

```
from glob import iglob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\user\your\path\**\*.csv'

all_rec = iglob(path, recursive=True)     
dataframes = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_rec)
big_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

Note that the three last lines can be expressed in one **single line**:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in iglob(path, recursive=True)), ignore_index=True)
```

You can find the documentation of `**` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob). Also, I used `iglob`instead of `glob`, as it returns an **iterator** instead of a list.

---

---

**EDIT: Multiplatform recursive function:**

You can wrap the above into a **multiplatform function** (Linux, Windows, Mac), so you can do:

```
df = read_df_rec('C:\user\your\path', *.csv)
```

Here is the function:

```
from glob import iglob
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd

def read_df_rec(path, fn_regex=r'*.csv'):
    return pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in iglob(
        join(path, '**', fn_regex), recursive=True)), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

Inspired from [MrFun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4746984/mrfun)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55436079/10358768):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

list_of_csv_files = glob.glob(directory_path + '/*.csv')
list_of_csv_files.sort()

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, list_of_csv_files), ignore_index=True)
```

**Notes:**

1. By default, the list of files generated through `glob.glob` is not sorted. On the other hand, in many scenarios, it's required to be sorted e.g. one may want to analyze number of sensor-frame-drops v/s timestamp.
2. In `pd.concat` command, if `ignore_index=True` is not specified then it reserves the original indices from each dataframes (i.e. each individual CSV file in the list) and the main dataframe looks like

   ```
       timestamp    id    valid_frame
   0
   1
   2
   .
   .
   .
   0
   1
   2
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   With `ignore_index=True`, it looks like:

   ```
       timestamp    id    valid_frame
   0
   1
   2
   .
   .
   .
   108
   109
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   IMO, this is helpful when one may want to manually create a histogram of number of frame drops v/s one minutes (or any other duration) bins and want to base the calculation on very first timestamp e.g.
   `begin_timestamp = df['timestamp'][0]`

   Without, `ignore_index=True`, `df['timestamp'][0]` generates the series containing very first timestamp from all the individual dataframes, it does not give just a value.

Answer (score 8):

Another one-liner with list comprehension which allows to use arguments with *[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)*.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'dir/{f}') for f in os.listdir('dir') if f.endswith('.csv')])
```

Comment: Perfect for me, since my csv filenames all ended with the same words, but my filenames started with a different datetimestamp

Answer (score 7):

If multiple CSV files are zipped, you may use *zipfile* to read all and concatenate as below:

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

ziptrain = zipfile.ZipFile('yourpath/yourfile.zip')

train = []

train = [ pd.read_csv(ziptrain.open(f)) for f in ziptrain.namelist() ]

df = pd.concat(train)
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternative using the `pathlib` library (often preferred over `os.path`).

This method avoids iterative use of pandas `concat()`/`apped()`.

From the pandas documentation: 
*It is worth noting that concat() (and therefore append()) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.*

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path("../relevant_directory")

df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in dir.glob("*.csv"))
df = pd.concat(df)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Sid's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe/36416258#36416258).

### To identify issues of missing or unaligned columns

Before concatenating, you can load CSV files into an intermediate dictionary which gives access to each data set based on the file name (in the form `dict_of_df['filename.csv']`). Such a dictionary can help you identify issues with heterogeneous data formats, when column names are not aligned for example.

Import modules and locate file paths:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas
from collections import OrderedDict
path =r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
```

Note: `OrderedDict` is not necessary, but it'll keep the order of files which might be useful for analysis.

### Load CSV files into a dictionary. Then concatenate:

```
dict_of_df = OrderedDict((f, pandas.read_csv(f)) for f in filenames)
pandas.concat(dict_of_df, sort=True)
```

Keys are file names `f` and values are the data frame content of CSV files.

Instead of using `f` as a dictionary key, you can also use `os.path.basename(f)` or other [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) methods to reduce the size of the key in the dictionary to only the smaller part that is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

os.system("awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' file*.csv > merged.csv")
```

Where `NR` and `FNR` represent the number of the line being processed.

`FNR` is the current line within each file.

`NR == 1` includes the first line of the first file (the header), while `FNR > 1` skips the first line of each subsequent file.

Comment: I bet this is a lot faster than using pandas concat!

Answer (score 2):

In case of an *unnamed* column issue, use this code for merging multiple CSV files along the x-axis.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

merged_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=0, header=0) for csv_file in glob.glob(
        os.path.join("data/", "*.csv"))], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

merged_df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for r, d, f in os.walk(csv_folder_path):
    for file in f:
        complete_file_path = csv_folder_path+file
        read_file = pd.read_csv(complete_file_path)
        new_df = new_df.append(read_file, ignore_index=True)


new_df.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which provides lots of data processing primitives and generates simple ad hoc code under the hood.
It is not supposed to be faster than pandas/polars, but sometimes it can be.

e.g. you could concat csv files into one for further reuse - here's the code:

```py
import glob

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
import pandas as pd


def test_pandas():
    df = pd.concat(
        (
            pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
            for filename in glob.glob("tmp/*.csv")
        ),
        axis=0,
        ignore_index=True,
    )
    df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
# took 20.9 s


def test_convtools():
    table = None
    for filename in glob.glob("tmp/*.csv"):
        table_ = Table.from_csv(filename, header=False)
        if table is None:
            table = table_
        else:
            table = table.chain(table_)

    table.into_csv("out_convtools.csv", include_header=False)
# took 15.8 s
```

Of course if you just want to obtain a dataframe without writing a concatenated file, it will take `4.63 s` and `10.9 s` correspondingly (*pandas is faster here because it doesn't need to zip columns for writing it back*).

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
file_path_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

file_iter = iter(file_path_list)

list_df_csv = []
list_df_csv.append(pd.read_csv(next(file_iter)))

for file in file_iter:
    lsit_df_csv.append(pd.read_csv(file, header=0))
df = pd.concat(lsit_df_csv, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can do it using [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption) on [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'/content/drive/My Drive/data/actual/comments_only' # Use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True,sort=True)
frame.to_csv('/content/drive/onefile.csv')
```